# How does Java actually spawn a process by ProcessBuilder on Windows platform?

Tags: java, windows, process, system-calls, processbuilder

How does Java actually spawn a process by ProcessBuilder on Windows platform ? By what mechanism, system call, etc is actually doing the job? Javadoc doesn't specify and from the behavior exhibited by spawning processes its not immediately obvious.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? It is eventually going to involve a system call at some point, but the specific details are very implementation dependent and therefore, not very useful in general.

Comment: You can find out by reading the source code.

Comment: And the short answer is that the JVM calls the Win32 function `CreateProcessW` from native code: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw.  (Or at least, that is what happens in Java 17.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder#start` [calls `ProcessImpl#start`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dbb2c4b6ac01d2a3367a2354213d3b4230dfbb96/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.java#L1109), which [calls the `ProcessImpl` constructor](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dbb2c4b6ac01d2a3367a2354213d3b4230dfbb96/src/java.base/windows/classes/java/lang/ProcessImpl.java#L159), which [calls `ProcessImpl#create`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dbb2c4b6ac01d2a3367a2354213d3b4230dfbb96/src/java.base/windows/classes/java/lang/ProcessImpl.java#L500) aka `Java_java_lang_ProcessImpl_create`, which [calls `processCreate`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dbb2c4b6ac01d2a3367a2354213d3b4230dfbb96/src/java.base/windows/native/libjava/ProcessImpl_md.c#L382), which [calls the Win32 syscall `CreateProcessW`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/dbb2c4b6ac01d2a3367a2354213d3b4230dfbb96/src/java.base/windows/native/libjava/ProcessImpl_md.c#L331).